# what am i missing in this simple readline(nodeJS) piece of code?

Tags: node.js, readline

Well, have no clue what am I missing.
I got a file with lines like that (time series you can say):

```
fs1,disk1,<date>,<value>
fs1,disk1,<date>,<value>
fs2,disk2,<date>,<value>
fs3,disk3,<date>,<value>
fs3,disk3,<date>,<value>
fs3,disk3,<date>,<value>
fs4,disk4,<date>,<value>
```

The lines are sorted (fs,disk,date)

so I want to read this file line by line with nodeJS [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line), and as long as i have the same fs,disk to concatante this date,value series into a string and then to store that sting inside the dictionary..
for some silly reason that I miss, its not doing so.

here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/disksTimeSeries/timeSeries')
});

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.send(index.html);
});

app.listen(3005);

var diskToTimeSeries = {};


var currDisk;
var prevDisk;
var currStr = "";
var seriesStr="";
var i = 0;
var disk;
var splitArr;

var data = {};
data['prevDisk'] = "";
data['seriesStr'] = "";


lineReader.on('line', function (line) {


    console.log(line);

    splitArr = line.split(",");

    disk = splitArr[0] + "," + splitArr[1];
    if (data['prevDisk']  && disk !== data['prevDisk'])
    {
        diskToTimeSeries[data['prevDisk']] = data['seriesStr'];
        data['seriesStr'] = "";
    }
    else
    {
        data['prevDisk'] = disk;
        data['seriesStr'] = data['seriesStr'] + (splitArr[2] + "," + splitArr[3] + "\n");
    }
    console.log(disk);
});



// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/disks', function(req, res) {

    var diskIds = req.query.ids.split(":");
    var resultStr = "";
    diskIds.forEach(function(diskName){
        resultStr += "disk name--" + diskName + "\n" + diskToTimeSeries[diskName];
    });
    res.send(resultStr);

});

module.exports = app;
```

What am I missing :( ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks hehe now its there :)

Comment: `data['seriesStr'] = data['seriesStr'] + (splitArr[2] + "," + splitArr[3] + "\n");` should be moved out of `else`. That should happen for every line.

Comment: im stupid, sorry for your time :(

Comment: It may not be the only problem, it's just the first one that I see. It's not a waste of time and someone may decide to post a full answer, so just be patient.